# Can we prove this inequality holds for some region?

Tags: inequality

Can we prove this inequality holds form some region
, if $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2>R^2$ then
$$
\begin{align}
\ -x\arctan(x)+0.5x-y\arctan(y)+0.4y<0\\
\end{align}
$$
As I can see from the WolframAlpha picture there is some region that is similar to $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2>R^2$ but I have no idea how we can prove that and find $R$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The picture suggests to take $a=0.5/2$, $b=0.4/2$ and $R\simeq 1/3$. We can bound $R$ more precisely 
looking for a big disk $D$ with this center $(a,b)$, which is contained in the white region.  Thus we have to show that if $(x,y)\in D$ then

$$-x\arctan(x)+0.5x-y\arctan(y)+0.4y\ge 0.$$

We use a fact that for each non-negative $t$ we have $\operatorname{arctan} t\le t$. Therefore we have $-t\operatorname{arctan} t\ge –t^2$ for each real $t$. Then

$$-x\arctan(x)+0.5x-y\arctan(y)+0.4y\ge$$ $$–x^2+0.5x-y^2+0.4y=$$ $$-(x-a)^2+a^2-(y-b)^2+b^2\ge a^2+b^2-R^2.$$

So $R=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=\sqrt{0.1025}=0.3201\dots.$ fits.

I thank to user8053696 for providing the picture:

[image]

But to find a small disk which contains the white region, we have to look for other, I think, not so simple arguments.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify why if $-x^2+0.5x-y^2+0.4y<0$ then $-x\arctan(x)+0.5x-y\arctan(y)+0.4y<0$? Because this circle will be inside closed region of function with arctan not outside. https://i.imgur.com/n9Xy2z1.png

Comment: For example, from 5>-5 doesn't follow that 5 is negative.

Comment: @user8053696 Thanks for the picture, I clarified my answer.